# Merge two Sorted Arrays in Java using Stream

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, java-stream

I have two sorted integer arrays. I am looking to merge them into one sorted array. I would like to use Java Stream to achieve this.

Can I do a nested stream?

```
Arrays.asList(nums1).stream()
            .forEach(i -> Arrays.asList(nums2).stream()
                    .forEach(j -> //compare i,j)
                            .collect as list// ;
```

For example, `[1,3,4]` and `[2,5]` should return `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: `int[] combo = Stream.of(nums1, nums2).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sorted().toArray();` would achieve this, but it could very likely be less efficient than "zipping" the two arrays together via a loop.

Comment: You don't have to use stream for *everything*

Answer (score 5):

When we apply `sorted()` operation on a stream pipeline, under the hood it'll allocate an array in memory that will be filled with elements of the stream and sorted.

To sort an array of reference type Java uses an implementation of the [*Timsort algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is good at spotting sorted chunks of data in the input (*`Arrays.asList()` that you've used in your example expects varargs `T`, so I assume we are talking about objects*).

Therefore, if we simply concatenate the two data sets it will still perform reasonably well.

```
String[] nums1 = {"1", "3", "4"};
String[] nums2 = {"2", "5"};
String[] merged = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(nums1), Arrays.stream(nums2))
    .sorted()
    .toArray(String[]::new);
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

In case if you want to use conditional logic to obtain a sorted resulting array, then you must go with a plain `for` loop. It's not a job for a stream.

Using imperative programming, it can be implemented like that:

```
String[] nums1 = {"1", "3", "4"};
String[] nums2 = {"2", "5"};

String[] merged = new String[nums1.length + nums2.length];
        
int pos1 = 0; // current index in the first array
int pos2 = 0; // current index in the second array

for (int i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
    if (pos2 >= nums2.length || pos1 < nums1.length // if the second array is exhausted or if both positions are valid and the current element in the first array is the lowest
        && nums1[pos1].compareTo(nums2[pos2]) < 0) {
        merged[i] = nums1[pos1++];
    } else {
        merged[i] = nums2[pos2++];
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams are nice but i recommend you this way because with streams you first have to change the arrays to streams only to work on them which could get expensive

```
public static String[] mergeAndSort(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
    int nums1Size = arr1.length;
    int nums2Size = arr2.length;

    String[] result = new String[nums1Size + nums2Size];  
    System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, result, 0, nums1Size);
    System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, result, nums1Size, nums2Size);

    Arrays.sort(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer [] arrOne = {1,3,40};
Integer [] arrTwo = {44,6,7};

private Integer[] flatTwoArray(Integer[] aa, Integer[] ab) {
    return Stream.of(aa,ab).flatMap(Stream::of).sorted().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).